# How to hide Google Map API Key in Django Template

Tags: javascript, django-templates

I want to hide Google Map API Key in js file.
Is it necessary and if so, is it possible?
Please help me.
Here it is:
`<script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>`

Comment: Hello. I think we need to know just a bit more.  Can you show more context as to where this script tag is being referenced?  What file are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm referring to Django template, that is, html file.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the best practice is to implement Usage Restriction as mentioned in Google API documentation.
https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#restricting-api-keys